# Add new item link icon position issue in IE7

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have fixed width site in sharepoint 2010. I have given fixed width to the content area. so that the page which has more columns, a horizontal scroll bar is shown eg: view all documents page. but when I move the scroll bar the add new item --PLUS ICON-- is not moving along with the text (issue is shown only in IE7).

Please anyone help

Regards
Binu

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the behaviour?